# Property "parser" is the wrong type (expected string/null but got `["@babel/eslint-parser"]`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to deploy the backend part of my project onto firebase. The backend of my project is located in the "functions" directory. I locate my functions directory and use the command. `firebase deploy --only functions`. However, I get this error. Here is a screenshot of my error:

[image]

Here is my `.eslintrc.js` where the error happens:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
   parser: ["@babel/eslint-parser"]
};
```

I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error. Any ideas why this is happening? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

> parser : "@babel/eslint-parser"

please refer docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/eslint-parser